# Send app for testing to multiple person (2000) without going to Apple approval process

Tags: ios, testflight, in-house-distribution, hockeyapp

I want send my app for testing to multiple users. I don’t want to go for Apple approval process.

I read about [Enterprise](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html) program. But is there any limit for number of users?

Is there any alternate option for this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Enterprise program has no limit of users, as long as it's an internal distribution (i.e. inside your company or something, not to random people) you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2,000 testers? I would suspect that you don't have 2,000 testers but that you want to distribute an app outside the app store.

The Enterprise program allows unlimited number of customers *within your company*. You pay $299 to join the program and you sign a legally binding contract that you do NOT make anything available to anyone who is not an employee of your company. If Walmart writes an app that Walmart is using internally, no problem sending it to 2,000 Walmart employees. Do you write an app for a company with 2,000 employees?

Answer (score 1):

I read about Enterprise program. But is there any limit for number of users?

**- NO**

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to create multiple binaries with different bundle identifier and profiles + app icons + splash images. **This may be against Apple policies**. I don't know about that at all. And yes, its highly not recommended. But I think, while development you can do that with some random name of the app which won't affect you in future.

E.g.

> com.company.MyFirstApp + app icons + splash images + functionalities
>
> com.company.MySecondApp + new app icons + new splash images + same functionalities

Cool thing? You can then send these binaries to 4000 people. But yeah, there'll be two apps which doing the same thing.

Once you're ready for production, you can re-set everything with exact thing you want and then submit it to store.

But wait, by doing such thing, it may cancelled your license for the account. Again don't do this.

Comment: How can I  send binaries to 4000 people? Should I have to upload it on TestFlight?

Comment: OK, I got it I was thinking that 2000 limit is for an account not for the app. I came to know that 2000 users limit is for per application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Testflight, there are other alternatives that don't require Apple review, such as HockeyApp or Crashalytics Beta:

https://www.playtestcloud.com/blog/testflight-alternatives-ios-android

Answer (score 0):

First, an answer to your question: yes, there is no user limitation for an Enterprise license.

And just a reminder: Whatever test tools you are choosing, you still need to abide by Apple distribution policy, such as 100 UDIDs in any ad-hoc provisioning profile and unlimited number of customers for enterprise distribution.

However, if you want to efficiently test your app, you can leverage some tools, such as HockeyApp. [Here](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb) you can find basic introductions about how to integrate hockeyapp, and [this post](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/app-management-2/how-to-organize-development-and-production-apps-for-distribution#hockeyapp-offers-four-pre-defined-release-types-) explains the application release types HockeyApp supports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestFlight together with a service like [BoardingBot](https://boardingbot.boorgle.com/) to distribute up to 2000 testers which is the current limit for external testers in TestFlight